# HTACCESS RERWITE not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

My current URL looks something like this

"portfolio/index.php?page=work"

I have written a rewrite rule in my .htaccess file to then swap this out so that the URL ends up looking like

"portfolio/work"

```
# ######################################################################
# # URL REWRITE                                                       #
# ######################################################################

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

This is put at the top of my .htaccess page and I am using the HTML5 Boilerplate .htacccess file https://html5boilerplate.com/

Is there something that I am missing?

EDIT:

Added a pastebin of the full .htaccess file.
The code is right at the top, and is slightly different than the original question as I was playing around to try get it working.

http://pastebin.com/63CJ67MJ

Comment: If you're using Apache, make sure that you have `mod_rewrite` enabled.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? are you getting a 404 error?

Comment: Just nothing happens to the URL. Stays the same. Reason I know that the .htaccess is pulling through is that I get an 500 error when I put in the incorrect code. So something is weird.

Comment: Is this htaccess located inside `portfolio` directory?

Comment: Yes. There is. Here is a imgur for the file structure http://imgur.com/tb7yFxL

Comment: Can you post your full .htaccess in question or provide a pastebin.com link

Comment: @anubhava added a pastebin in the question

Comment: Does `domain.com/portfolio/index.php?page=work` work?

Comment: locally the file is just localhost/portfolio/index.php?page=work and that works yes. Havent tried it live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the rule is conflicting with other rules in your htaccess as your rule do not have a Last [L] flag at the end, try :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, if your .htaccess is being read or not. Then, the contents of your RewriteLog when testing.

RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log"

RewriteLogLevel 9

Comment: This link will also useful for you . http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Okay nevermind, the HTACCESS file is working. Just not getting that rewrite right.